# CSS transform rotate origin dynamically

Tags: asp.net, html, css-transitions

So before I shoot myself I need help with a css/html problem. I'm a .NET programmer and have not had to delve into html or css much. I have some charts that are stored as images and rather than display them horizontal they want them vertical. So for example an image would be 75px high and 900px wide. They are displayed in a Div that goes across a screen. So to display them vertically I did some transformations on the images - rotate(-90). No problem. The problem arises with the origin part. I want the images that are in the Div to line up vertically against the left side of the div container and this container is another Div. But I have to monkey with the margins to get the container to go to the right part of the screen. An of course when screen size changes this won't work anyways. Gotta be something I'm missing?  This is my code I am using:

CSS

```
   .columnMain
{   
    float: left;  
    **margin-left: 440px;**  
    **margin-top:-425px;**  
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */  
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Opera */  
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;  
    position:relative;  
}
div.container  
{  
    width: 99%;  
    margin-left: 2px;  
    padding: 0px;  
    height:600px;  
    background-color:#000000;  
    border:1px solid white;  
    top:225px;  
    position:absolute;  
}
```

I made the problem area bold above. And the HTML/ASP.NET below

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="columnMain">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="CMGraph" runat="server">
                <uc3:MGraph ID="MGraph1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Inherit" 
                    EnableViewState="True" ViewStateMode="Enabled" />**This is the image/chart that has been created elsewhere**
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Tinkering with origins does not matter as I need to use a negative number to bring back the Div and its contents to left side of the div.container. So I need to know if I can do something  more eloquent than what I am doing now and that will actually work correctly regardless of screen size?